# Is socket.io the WebRTC or WebSocket or something else?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, webrtc, sip

I'm new to [socket.io](http://socket.io/). In Realtime (Web) Applications, we used to choose whether it should be WebRTC or WebSocket (or even SIP, still?) technologies.

What exactly is `socket.io` in this case please?

Answer (score 14):

#### WebSockets

`socket.io` is a popular open source library implemented on both backend and client side. This library is based on [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) which allow a communication between a **SERVER** and a **CLIENT**.

---

#### WebRTC

On the other hand, [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) is a WebAPI which comes with basically 3 things:

- **R**eal **T**ime **C**ommunication between two browsers (no server needed), a peer to peer connection (P2P)
- Media Streaming (Audio and Video)
- **R**eal **T**ime **C**ommunication Data Chanel (stream any data on P2P)

---

The main difference is that WebSockets needs **A SERVER** and it is based on *publish/subscribe pattern* where you can send raw data back and forth, without having any special data handling by default. In contrast, WebRTC has a lot of functions already in place which can be used to handle Audio/Video streaming and also the raw data with data chanel.

---

For more info I recommend reading on MDN links I provided above and also check [this](https://www.slideshare.net/micheledisalvatore/webrt-socketio-building-a-skypelike-video-chat-with-native-javascript) very cool slides on *sockets* and *webRTC*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make video or audio communication services use WebRTC for browser build in support and write the discovery and signaling. webrtc have awesome features like P2P connections and data encryption.

WebRTC client side (browser) features like get video and audio data with good support in evergreen browsers: http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/#interop

And socket.io is good for build centralized pub / sub apps like text chat

You can make connections with WebRTC without socket.io but both works fine if you use socket.io for help in signaling

Comment: Thanks. But you confused me even more. What exactly is `socket.io` then? Is it based on WebRTC? Or WebSockets? Or something else?

Comment: Is diferente things, socket.io is one node.js module for work with websockets and fallbacks to websockets like pooling
And WebRTC is one technology for make video and audio comunications